# Continuity of the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} 3,\text{ if }0\leq x\leq1\\ 4,\text{ if }1< x<3\\ 5,\text{ if }3\leq x\leq10\\ \end{cases}$

Tags: functions, continuity

> Check the continuity of the function $f$ where
>   $$
> f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 3\quad,\text{ if }0\leq x\leq1\\
> 4\quad,\text{ if }1< x<3\\
> 5\quad,\text{ if }3\leq x\leq10\\
> \end{cases}
> $$

**Case 1:** At $x$=$1$
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to{1^+}}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to{1^+}}4=4\\
\lim_\limits{x\to{1^-}}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to{1^-}}3=3\neq4=\lim_\limits{x\to{1^+}}f(x)
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$

**Case 2:** At $x$=$3$
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to{3^+}}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to{3^+}}5=5\\
\lim_\limits{x\to{3^-}}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to{3^-}}4=4\neq5=\lim_\limits{x\to{3^+}}f(x)
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is not continuous at $x=3$

**Case 3:** Let $x$=$c$ where $1<c<3$
$$
f(c)=4\\
\lim_\limits{x\to{c}}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to{c}}4=4=f(c)\\
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous at $1<x<3$

What about Case 4 and Case 5 ?

where,

**Case 4:** $0\leq x<1$

**Case 5:** $3<x\leq 10$

do I need to verify continuity in the open interals $(0,1)$ and $(3,10)$ and then $\lim_\limits{x\to{0^+}}f(x)=f(0)$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to{10^-}}f(x)=f(10)$ ?

**My Attempt**

**Case 4:** $0\leq x<1$

Let $x=c$ where $c\in(0,1)$
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to c}3=3=f(c)
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous for $x\in(0,1)$
And
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+}f(x)=3=f(0)
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous at $0$

**Case 5:** $3<x\leq10$

Let $x=c$ where $c\in(3,10)$
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to c}5=5=f(c)
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous for $x\in(3,10)$
And
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to 10^-}f(x)=5=f(10)
$$
$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous at $10$

Is it the right way to approach the given problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those cases, for each $\varepsilon>0$ you take $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is a subset of the interval that you're dealing with ($[0,1)$ or $(3,10]$). Then$$|y-x|<\delta\iff y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\implies\bigl|f(y)-f(x)\bigr|=0<\varepsilon.$$So, for instance, in the **Case 4** this proves that$$|y-x|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(y)-3\bigr|=0\text{ (since $f(y)=3$)}<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: could u pls simplify a bit and explain as I solved other cases ?

Comment: @ss1729 I've added another sentenc. I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: pls check i have edited the question. Hope my doubt is clear ?